# Using Dropdownlist to navigate in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

Hi i am using a dropdown list to populate the products using :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Product", new SelectList(Model.Products, "ProductUrl", "ProductName"))
```

Which is rendered as :

```
<select id="Product" name="Product">
<option value="http://www.domain.co.uk/test?specs=5">produc1</option>

<option value="http://www.domain.co.uk/test?specs=6">product2</option>

<option value="http://www.domain.co.uk/test?specs=7">product3</option>

</select>
```

What I want to do is when the certain product is selected the system should navigate to the option value of that product, for instance if product1 is selected by the client from the dropdown list , the website should navigate to http://www.domain.co.uk/test?specs=5 which is the option value for that product1,

Any ideas of how to do this..??
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either of the following methods, Pure Javascript or jQuery:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#Product").change(function()
{
     location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dYTp2/)**

**Javascript:**

```
<select id="Product" name="Product" onChange='location.href = this.value'>
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dYTp2/1/)

Comment: You don't need the `':selected'` filter. `$(this).val()` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Adam, It's an early morning and was a late night :)

Answer (score 2):

This is really bad usability from a html perspective -- hyperlinks are there for navigation. Forms are for doing things with data.

That said, what you need to do is capture the onchange event of the drop down in javascript then use the selected value to navigate to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to add an onchange handler

```
Html.DropDownList("Product", new SelectList(Model.Products, "ProductUrl", "ProductName"), new {onchange="javascript:location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"})
```

Or you could use the jquery method of Rionmonster which does the same.